# How to solve "Java 8 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent Java runtime." in VSCode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, salesforce, apex

I'm always getting [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG35D.png) in VSCode from [this XML extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml)

The thing is that I've already installed **JRE8**, **JDK8** and **JDK11** from **Oracle**.

When I type `java -version` in CMD I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5zHM.png)

How can this one be solved out?

P.S. VSCode version is the latest available. System: Windows 10 Pro, latest available updates.

Comment: Have you read the "Requirements" section on the plugin description: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml It contains some actions you have to perform. Note: because Oracle Java is no longer free for commercial use you may want to use AdoptOpenJDK or a different OpenJDK variant instead. For example OpenJDK installer has the option to set JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: probbly by adding your java 11 /bin folder to system PATH variable. Or setting new JAVA_HOME variable. One of those should work

Comment: Robert, yeah, I've read the requirements, installed everything I need (as I wrote in the question description), but still got this error. What about AdoptOpenJDK - I'll try this in case nothing works with Oracle, cause for my preferences I need Oracle now.

Comment: mlecz, Tried setting new JAVA_HOME variable, ended up like this - `The JAVA_HOME environment variable does not point to a Java runtime.`

Comment: BTW, as of vscode-xml 0.15.0, Java is no longer required to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.9` for `JAVA_HOME` variable.